# File output error using MPI

Tags: c, mpi, icc

I have an MPI program running on the Xeon Phi Coprocessor with the MPIICC compiler.

My code runs fine until I finalize MPI and try to print my results to a file.

---

I'll start by describing the finalization:

```
MPI_Win_free(&win);
MPI_Finalize();


// After finalizing, all print statements in this area of 
// the code print for all MPI nodes (even though they have 
// been finalized)
printf("testing\n");

return 0;
}
```

The final `printf` statement prints for all MPI nodes, even though they have been finalized.

---

So, ok, strange behavior--I don't care.  I put an if statement such that the results only print if the rank is equal to 0:

```
if (rank == 0) {...}
```

This works, even after finalization.  Next, I change my print statements over to file write statements:

```
...
MPI_Finalize();

if (rank == 0){
    FILE *file = fopen("output.txt","w"); 
    fclose(file);
}

return 0;

}
```

And I get a segmentation fault.  I cannot figure out what is going on.  I have looked around, tried everything... not really sure what is happening, or even what could be going wrong.  I should have all the requisite permissions.

---

An added note: if I do not close the file, I don't get a segmentation fault (or print to it).

This seems to fail generally.

Comment: Are you giving fclose a `NULL` pointer ... ? I don't see any promises in the `man` pages that it will handle `NULL` pointers OK.

Comment: The stuff I was looking at said something to the effect that opening a file with mode "w" should just create the file.  I guess it probably is giving a NULL pointer.  I will check and delete this if it turns out that that is the case.  Not sure what my question would be at that point--not sure if I am missing permissions on the coprocessor.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that opening the file may fail, resulting in a NULL pointer. Why don't you add a print statement to verify your assumption that the file is successfully opened? (ie. try something like `printf("Pointer value: %p\n", (void *)file);`)

Comment: @JefréN. Yep, you are right, thanks man.  Looks like I need to use MPI File functions. Still new to C, thought it was something that I was doing.  Not sure if I should post the answer on how to print with MPI, or just delete.  What do you think?

Comment: `MPI_Finalize` cleans up the MPI system - it might, but is not required to end the MPI processes, and with most MPI implementations it won't. But you should generally not make further MPI calls after the finalisation. Creating files only works with filesystems mounted read-write. Always check the result from `fopen` for being non-NULL.

Comment: I think you might as well [leave it/ post the answer]. You could delete it if you want, though... I won't complain either way. ;)